# Address Parser for Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is anyone aware of an address parser plugin for Ruby?

I might have to use one of the paid webservices but thought there might be a plugin.

Another thought is go down the NLP route where I could build up a database over time.

Does anybody use any NLP plugin for ruby?

I want to use it to logically parse and sanitise something like this from the HTML:

```
  <address><strong>HALL (J&amp;E) LTD</strong><br />Head Office<br />
    Questor House<br />
    191 Hawley Road<br />
    Dartford<br />
    Kent <br />
    DA1 1PU</address>
    <p class="tel"><strong>Tel:</strong> +44 (0)1322 223456</p>
    <p class="fax"><strong>Fax:</strong> +44 (0)1322 291458</p>
    <p><strong>Website:</strong> <a target="_blank" href="http://www.jehall.co.uk">www.jehall.co.uk</a></p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto&#58;helpline&#64;jehall&#46;co&#46;uk?subject=Enquiry%20from%20Defence%20Suppliers%20Directory&amp;cc=defenceenquiries&#64;armedforces&#46;co&#46;uk">helpline&#64;jehall&#46;co&#46;uk</a></p>
</div>
```

Any suggestions gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have some success with Googles geocoding service. This can return structured addresses. There are ruby gems for interfacing with Googles maps API

Comment: This has the advantage that you can verify that the address actually exists (in most cases) especially if you have postal or zip codes

Comment: I think this is my default way if there is nothing out of the box.  It makes a whole lot of sense.  It just comes down to cost then.

Comment: There are some edge cases for which this solution doesn't work, for example when an address isn't indexed by Google because it is new or omitted.